# Excel VBA Macro: Copying cells by reference

Tags: excel, vba

I am creating a macro in Excel to copy data from one sheet to another within the same workbook.  Currently, the code operates as so:

```
Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
Dim destSheet As Worksheet
Dim numCases As Integer
Dim i As Integer

numCases = 10
Set destSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Raw_Data")
Set sourceSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Formatted_Data")

For i = 1 To numCases
    destSheet.Cells(i,1).Value = sourceSheet.Cells(1,i).Value
Next
```

This code works properly in that it copies the value from one sheet to the other and places it in the correct cell.  The issue is that I need the cell to be populated as a reference value back to sheet "Raw_Data".  In other words, when I select a cell in "Formatted_Data", I need the formula bar to show something like:
'Raw_Data'!C1
but instead all I get is the numerical value.  Is there some way that I can perform a copy, or set a value and maintain the reference??

Thanks,

Barret

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace

`destSheet.Cells(i,1).Value = sourceSheet.Cells(1,i).Value`

With

`sourceSheet.Cells(1,i).Formula = "=" & destSheet.Name & "!" & destSheet.Cells(i,1).Address(False,False)`

Comment: I will give this a try and report back.  Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  This set me on the correct path.  What I actually needed was the following:       `destSheet.Cells(i,1).Formula = "=" & "'" & sourceSheet.Name & "'" & "!" & sourceSheet.Cells(1,i).Address(False,False)`

Comment: @BarretBrown Ah. Glad you got it. That is what I wrote at first, but I edited it after re-reading your question again. So much for 2nd guessing!