# Range-variable changes during Worksheet_change and I don't know how

Tags: worksheet-function

I'm having a weird problem, luckily I barely have any other code in yet so I could narrow it down to it's source.
My problem is easier to read from the code than my description but I'll try anyway:
-I'm trying to remember a range which is cut within my workbook to enable "Undo" later
-I found a great function which tells me the range of cut cells (returns as "GetCopiedRange", function named the same too)
-Function works and returns correct value but later within Worksheet_Change the range is suddenly different without anything to give it a new value

TL;DR: How can CutRange.Address in following code be different when I select a range and after when I change a value in a range?

```
Dim CutRange As Range

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
If Application.CutCopyMode = xlCut Then
    Call GetCopiedRange 'This function changes value of variable "GetCopiedRange" (Range) to the range that is cut to clipboard
    Set CutRange = GetCopiedRange 'Save the range under a new variable because if I refer straight to GetCopiedRange later, it doesn't work
    MsgBox ("Cut range: " & CutRange.Address)
End If
'This sub works perfectly. If a range is cut to clipboard, Msgbox tells the range correctly
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Not CutRange Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox CutRange.Address
End If
'This sub works incorrectly(!?) CutRange.address is somehow now the destination of paste instead of where it was cut. How did it change in between?
'Even though when cut-paste operation is carried out, change occurs twice: first to the cut range and then the paste range. Even during the first one, CutRange.Address is somehow already changed to the paste range address
End Sub
```

EDIT: I don't see how the contents of said Function could be affecting this outcome, I hope we don't have to go there since it's a copied function much more complicated than I can understand. However, when I tried to remove the CutRange from all this and refer straight to GetCopiedRange in Worksheet_Change, I got an error "couldn't get data from clipboard" which is an error message inside the function. However since I'm using CutRange-variable I can't see how that one could be changing

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found the answer to my own question and revealed myself as a noobie or an idiot.

Fix: When I made a string instead of a range to track the cut range, the value stays as it should. Correct me if I'm wrong but it seems when you SET a RANGE to match another range, the first one will automatically change with the latter.

Next question: Is there a way to save a range as a range without changing it's value unless I say so?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a complete answer with example code, but rather a suggestion.  It sounds like you need to read and learn more about variables that are by value  vs by reference.

The concept sounds to be the root of your issue.   When you refer to something by value, your code holds the value of that object, and therefore isn't impacted if other things make changes to the original object.

When you refer to something by reference, you are merely "pointing" to that object.  Therefore, if something changes the value of that object, then all references to that object will see the new value.

Does that make sense?

Here are a couple of posts that touch on the concept of copying values vs accessing data or an object by reference.   If you search, you can probably find better examples that are more on point to your question, but at least this is a start.

[Excel VBA Macro: Copying cells by reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14884381/excel-vba-macro-copying-cells-by-reference)

[Excel VBA Assignment by value or by reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36945129/excel-vba-assignment-by-value-or-by-reference)